# Form validation not fired after submition

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

Im using Jquery mobile,Phonegap, and jquery validation to validate a contact form .
so the problem occurs  when i go from an index page to my contact form page using a link in my index page.then when i try to validate my form  using  the submit button,my form is been submitted even if the form is not valid.But when i make my contact form my index page that means i don't navigate between pages my form validation works very well.
here's the code of my contact page :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Plane</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/inscription.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).on("pageinit", "#main", function() {

    $("#add").validate({

    rules:
     {
      "name":{required:true},
      "comment":{required:true}
      }

    });

}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div  data-theme="b" data-role="page" id="main">
<div  data-theme="b" data-role="header"  >
<a href="index.html">index</a>
<h1>Inscription</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
     <form id="add" action="">
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
                            <label for="nom">
                                Nom
                            </label>
                            <input name="name" id="name" placeholder="name" value="" type="text" />
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
                            <label for="prenom">
                                Prénom
                            </label>
                            <input name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="comment" value="" type="text" />
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>

                        <input id="submit" data-theme="c" type="submit" data-inline="true" value="submit">
                        <input  id="reset" type="reset" data-inline="true" value="reset" />


      </form>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my index page :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>plane</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
//*********************************************************
// Wait for Cordova to Load
//*********************************************************

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-theme="b" data-role="page" id="main">
<div  data-theme="b" data-role="header">
<h1>plane</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
some content
<a href="contact.html" data-role="button">begin</a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try these url for validation
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.min.js

```
   <html>

  <head>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Gestion des tests</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/inscription.css"/>
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js">        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">      </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"      src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
             <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
           $(document).on("pageshow", "#main", function() {

          $("#add").validate({

         rules:
              {
                 "name":{required:true},
                 "comment":{required:true}
             }

         });
     }); 
 </script>
 </head>
<body>

     <div  data-theme="b" data-role="page" id="main">
     <div  data-theme="b" data-role="header"  >
         <a href="index.html">index</a>
          <h1>Inscription</h1>
     </div>
     <div data-role="content">
            <form id="add" action="">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
                        <label for="nom">
                            Nom
                        </label>
                        <input name="name" id="name" placeholder="name" value="" type="text" />
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                       <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
                        <label for="prenom">
                            Prénom
                        </label>
                        <input name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="comment" value="" type="text" />
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                    <input id="submit" data-theme="c" type="submit" data-inline="true"    value="submit">
                    <input  id="reset" type="reset" data-inline="true" value="reset" />


        </form>

    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>​
```

Comment: thank you for your reply,i used your link that you gave me but still not working.I don't udestand because when i use the same html file in my browser just for testing the validation is fired but in the native android application no error is showed.Thank you in advance